# Subquery inside include in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a C# application with Entity Framework 5. The data model looks the following way:

```cs
public class Challenge
{
    //Other properties
    public ICollection<UserChallenge> UserChallenges { get; set; }
}

public class UserChallenge
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ChallengeId { get; set;}

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    public int? GroupId { get; set; }

    //Other properties
}
```

Users participated in the challenges, and I stored this information in the `UserChallenges` table. Also, users were divided into groups of 10 participants each.

I want to write a query that returns all challenges in which the user participated, and the result contains UserChallenges from the user's group.

The problem is that I want to do it in one query and optimize it as much as possible.

I have the following code right now:

```cs
public Task<Challenge[]> GetChallenges(int profileId)
{
    context.Challenges
           .Where(c => c.UserChallenges.Any(uc => uc.ProfileId == profileId))
           .Include(c => c.UserChallenges);
           //I need to use GroupId somehow here
}
```

However, it contains all user challenges.
Is it possible to filter them?
Probably I can use Included filters which were introduced in EF 5.

Comment: Can't you add another `Where` filter and use it all the same as you did it with  `UserChallenges`? e.g. `context.Challenges.Where(c => c.UserChallenges.Any(uc => uc.ProfileId == profileId)).Where(c => c.UserChallenges.Any(uc => uc.GroupId == whatever))`

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is query it starting from user challenges instead of challenges. e.g. `context.UserChallenges.Where(c => c.ProfileId == profileId).Where(c => c.GroupId == whatever).Select(c => c.Challenges);`

Comment: I don't know the value of `whatever`, I should load it in a query and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a groupId check to filter out the challenges based on profileId and groupId

```
public Task<Challenge[]> GetChallenges(int profileId, int groupId)
{
    context.Challenges
           .Where(c => c.UserChallenges.Any(uc => uc.ProfileId == profileId && uc.GroupId == groupId))
           .Include(c => c.UserChallenges);
}
```

and if you want to include UserChallenges only for that specific group you can add a Where method call in the Include method.

```
public Task<Challenge[]> GetChallenges(int profileId, int groupId)
{
    context.Challenges
           .Where(c => c.UserChallenges.Any(uc => uc.ProfileId == profileId && uc.GroupId == groupId))
           .Include(c => c.UserChallenges.Where(uc => uc.GroupId == groupId));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know `groupId`. I should determine it dynamically.

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting a group?

Comment: The UserChallenge belongs to the group. There are 10 participants in each group.